# Best way to use SQLite as back end

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that has various data and using python, I can access this database locally, perform calculations on the data housed in the database and return results.

I want to take it to the next step and deploy this online as a backend to a webpage whereby the front end user would be able to click and invoke one of several python scripts, and have the data passed back into the web framework.
If possible I would like the user be able to update the data from the web framework, i.e. not have it read only.

I'm very much a newbie and content to thrash around, what i'm struggling with is the best workflow to move forward.

SQLite -> Python -> Javascript running in browser? Whereby a user would click a button that would use javascript to invoke the python script, the data then being passed back as some kind of json or xml or similar?

Is it better to try and do the whole thing using python using something like web2py?

Are there any frameworks that make this easy like wordpress (which I think is php)

Comment: sqlalchemy could be used as your ORM and you can select whichever Rdb you want underneath mysql, postgres, etc  For frameworks there are too many to list.

Comment: You should remove the last question, but that is clearly an opinion-based question based on a product recommendation -- not allowed on Stack Overflow.  (And, there are many other choices; I might argue for Postgres.)

Comment: Re web frameworks; Using [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits) can be pretty easy; e.g: [wiki.py](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/master/examples/web/wiki/wiki.py) which uses an sqlite database.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've taken out the last comment although I wasn't trying to recommend a product. I think I'm going to continue with web2py, the Github page seems to have a script that migrates sqlite into the DAL necessary to build an app.